# How to use gcc in Ubuntu without Root privilege?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, gcc, sudo

I'm using an Ubuntu server to run npm install.

I have to use an account which is not sudoer to run services.

I would say this is a service account.

However, when I type gcc --version, it show permission denied.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied
```

I found out that gcc is in charge of root account.

So my question is that is there any way I can just use gcc to run npm install without changing any permission?

I'm not allowed to give sudo permission to this service account.

I ran "ls -lah /usr/bin/gcc" and the result is

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 May 21  2019 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7
```

Comment: please run 'ls -lah /usr/bin/gcc' and give us the output info.

Comment: @Gunther I ran the commend and it says "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 May 21  2019 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-7"

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx  means its executable by everone.

Please do the same for 'ls -lah /usr/bin/gcc-7''

Comment: @Gunther It says "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec  4  2019 /usr/bin/gcc-7 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7"

Comment: @Gunther I ran for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 and it says "-rwx------ 1 root root 1023K Dec  4  2019 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7"

Comment: AFAIK these permissions are wrong. I would try to reinstall the compiler:
apt-get remove --purge gcc-7
apt install gcc-7

Also
apt install gcc

as gcc version 7 is relatively old

Comment: @Gunther so is it supposed to be rwxr-xr-x?

Comment: This is the outout of an Ubuntu 20.04 Server:

ls -la /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1158288 Mär  9  2022 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9

So yes. Your permissions look good now